# Fastest Way To Download Website Data C#

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

I am writing an Rcon in Visual Studio for Black Ops. I know its an old game but I still have a server running.

I am trying to download the data from this link

### [Black Ops Log File](http://logs.gameservers.com/108.61.227.224:3114/096d9a93-1a03-4804-a87b-faa81dae651f)

I am using this code.

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string raw = wc.DownloadString(logFile);
```

Which take between 6441ms to 13741ms according to Visual Studio.

Another attempt was...

```
string html = null;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(logFile);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
request.Proxy = null;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Which also takes around 6133ms according to VS debugging.
I have seen other rcon respond to commands really quickly. Mine take on best 5000ms which is not really acceptable. How can I download this this information quicker. I am told it shouldn't take this long??? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is probably on the network side, even if I open the link you posted with my browser take more than 6 seconds to receive the entire file

Comment: How can I read half the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how long the server takes to answer:

[image]

In the future you can debug such problems yourself using network tools such as Fiddler or by profiling your code to see what takes the longest amount of time.